# Can gravity of an object in cloth physics be changed to pull inwards itself?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to make an animation of a bra on a woman that stays the same size and streches as she grows and expands. Using the cloth physics I've managed for the bra to fall downwards over the chest and break apart as she grows, but that isn't the effect I'm looking for, the bra is not a falling cloth per se, it's kind of an elastic that streches around the expanding body.

Is there any way to change the gravity direction in the cloth physics to flow inwards the object, so as to leave the bra " sticking" to the skin and strech while the body expands?

I've tried to use the shrinkwrap modifier but the skin pertrudes thru the bra and breaks apart too fast... The streching illusion lasts only 3 frames... :/

Comment: I haven't tried this... but in absence of anything else: I guess that the simulation have a hard time dealing with expanding geometry. Maybe it will work better if you reverse the process where you go from the maximum size. My guess is that cloth would be able to handle this better.

Comment: Is it possible to break the bra in three seperate objects, left cup, right cup, top-neck string and bottom-back string... Add to the top-neck string and bottom-back string soft bodies physics in order for it to be like a rubber string, add cloth physics to the two cups, and join the vertices of the end of the top-neck string to the top part of the cups and join the vertices of the bottom-back strings to the sides of the cup?

Comment: Is it possible to join different objects by their vertices that have different physics and still hold together?